# View size reduces after hiding tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my iPhone app.

I am using `UINavigationControllers` in `UITabBarController`.

Like:

Tab Bar:

- Navigation Controller.

  - View Controller1.
- Navigation Controller.

  - View Controller2.

---

View Controllerx from any of above view controllers.

When I navigates to the View Controllerx.

I am hiding the tab bar.

**The problem is that tab bar is hiding but view size reduces.
And white space appears at bottom.**

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj_tipcalc animated:YES];
[obj_tipcalc release];
```

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your navigation controller's view lies within the view of your UITabBarController and it's not filling the entire screen.
Simply try to resize it:

```
 ...
 CGRect biggerFrame = tabBarController.view.frame;
 biggerFrame.size.height += tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
 tabBarController.view.frame = biggerFrame ;
 ...
```

To bring back the original layout:

```
...
CGRect smallerFrame = tabBarController.view.frame;
smallerFrame.size.height -= tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
tabBarController.view.frame = smallerFrame;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful.In ViewwillAppear set the frame.

Comment: when tabbar hidden is false then again set frame

Answer (score 0):

Change the frame of the view after hiding tabbar:

```
CGRect *rect=view1.frame;
rect.size.height+=44;
view1.frame=rect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `loadView` on the viewController contained in within the TabBar. This will reload the view with proper size